# Grafana: human readable name of custom variable

Tags: variables, grafana

I have a task to create custom (not Query!) Grafana variable with values, which to be used in sql where clause.

Assume, values are:

```
      is null, is not null,  is null or is not null
```

And in drop-down list user must see "human readable" titles:

```
     'Empty', 'Not Empty', 'All'.
```

I found, how this problem solved for sql-query variables.  But it's not my case, obviously.

As a solution I tried to write in "Values separated by comma" the following:

```
 Empty: is null,
 Not Empty: is not null,
 All: is null or is not null
```

But it does not work: in drop-down list I see this key-values pairs: "Empty: is null, ..."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Custom` type variable must have specific value/format (works fine for Grafana 8.2.4, it may not be supported by lower Grafana major versions):

```
Empty : is null, Not Empty : is not null, All : is null or is not null
```

Spaces are important.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for delay with reaction!